# Regular expression for currency fomat

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to find a piece of regex to match a currency value.

if the price is 1000 in USD then need to validate in the format 1,000.00 or 1,000 But in the case of German it is opposite like 1.000,00 or 1.000 I need to validate the entered amount is in usd format or german format.user can enter with or without decimal.

Comment: Do you have anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to process such information, why not [`parseCurrency()`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) function? Should there be any error it will yield `false`.

Regular expression, I think in this case at least, should be avoided since there is functionality which is already provided.

That being said, you could use something like so `(^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)$|(^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?$)`.

Comment: Unfortunately the given RegExp string will not work as hoped: In case of a German formatted number `12.345.678,00` the RegExp will match the first 5 digits only: `12.34`. By changing the RegExp to `(^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)$|^(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?$)`  (putting the `^` and `$` signs into the subpatterns) I managed to get it to work as expected.

Comment: @cars10: Weird... but glad it worked for you. I have updated my answer according to your finds.